What is the relationship between binary oppositions and the system of signs in structuralism?
As I understand it, the structuralist paradigm proposes a few key tenets:

Systems (i.e. language, mythology, literature, anthropology) can be analysed as a system of signs.
A sign consists of a signifier (the form of a sign) and a signified (the concept, or abstraction, of a sign).
Signs gain their meaning not through their positive content but rather their interrelation. (To this point, Saussure claimed that meaning is relational, rather than substantial.)
A fundamental organisational unit of a system is the binary opposition (i.e. life/death, good/evil, masculine/feminine).

To what extent does a system consist of signs vs binary oppositions? The question I am asking specifically refers to the anatomy or morphology of a structuralist system. Does a system consist of two independent subsystems (binaries & signs), or are binaries derived from signs (or vice versa)? Signs appear to be the structural unit of systems, are binaries, then, the functional unit of a system, or something else entirely?
My own intuition about the matter is that: a system consists exclusively of signs, & that the binary oppositions develop as a product of the system of signs. However, I have no concrete evidence for this.

Indeed signs are the structural unit of systems while binaries are the organizational or operationally functional unit of a system which is subtly more higher-level and closer to the Derrida-like differance interpretation of semantics of languages, since the binary could be said to be the strongest differance unit ever organizable in a system of inter-related signs. It's like magnetics in physics, though there're signs of north and south pole, but when you use it, it's always organized with two opposite poles without monads...

The first element of cognition is the creation of a unary (or unaries): the mental delineation of a category (or perhaps paradigm or prototype is more on point) of an object which:

represents a kind of thing fulfilling certain purposes or properties
establishes the thing as whole and indivisible in itself
conceptually separates the thing as independent of its background

Thus, when we use the term 'chair', we invoke an object which:

has certain properties useful for the act of sitting
cannot be taken in part: i.e.:

no part of a chair is the chair, and…
a object can either be used as a chair or not, nothing in-between


the object can (theoretically) be moved independently of the background without losing its 'chairness'

The second part of °2 is not strictly what we think of as a binary. It's closer to an inflection: some perceptual element that we signify as distinct from the background without really making a comparison to the background. A proper binary is a relationship between two unaries that diverge on some measurable quality, where both unaries are distinct from a background. This a light might be on or off — a binary distinction based on luminosity — but both the 'on' light and the 'off' light are objects distinct from the background, and the background has no property of on-ness or off-ness.
So, a sign is a unary that has a relationship of 'distinct from' to the background, and various types of relationships to other signs. One of those relationships to other signs is binary-ness.
